# Kakfa Topics are getting deleted when logs are deleted?

Tags: apache-kafka

Here I installed Kafka and created a topic by command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic inventory-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

and then listed all the topics by command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

that's working fine and also not getting deleted when reboot because i changed the directory internally.

But the issue here is that when I encounter an error, it gets stored in the log files. When we delete the log files, the system starts working again. However, after deleting the logs, all the topics are also getting deleted. Suppose I am working on a project with huge data in a topic. What would happen if an error occurs and the data gets deleted? How can I ensure that the data always remains, and topics are only deleted when I want them to be?

Kafka dir is

```
C:\kafka_2.13-3.6.1
```

it has following files

```
bin
config
libs 
license
logs
my-logs-kafka (directory path given in server.properties and zookeeper.properties)
site-docs
```

Here is my server.properties file

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# This configuration file is intended for use in ZK-based mode, where Apache ZooKeeper is required.
# See kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults
#

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=C:/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/my-logs-kafka/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
#log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Tell me how to prevent this.

Comment: What "error" are you referring to? And where did you read to delete all topics to fix any such error? Server logs are not the same as topic log segments

Comment: I copy my comment here too, you're facing issue because you're on windows OS.

Comment: @OneCricketeer : I think he deleted all zookeeper data, that's why he lost his topics. and sometime zookeeper is not working well in Windows and there's no solution other then erase it's data and reset it

Comment: @OneCricketeer : I didn't read to delete all topics to fix error. Please read again I said that the directory you provided in zookeeper.properties and in server.properties for logs . If any error comes those logs will get stored in that folder and until you don't delete those logs kafka would not run, but deleting that also deletes the existing topics. Suppose i am working on a topic and error comes and stored in that log file and if i deleted than topics also getting deleted. If you know any way that if error comes tell a way to resolve without loosing topics.

Comment: @Abhishek Server logs with errors are not stored with topic data, though. You can delete data from one topic rather than all topics, too, or only server logs without deleting any topics... Please clarify what type of error you're referring to

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing what Kafka is calling log directory with server log.
In the server.properties file, there's a configuration called `log.dir` ; This one is to tell Kafka where to store DATA, but the server logs is specified by default in an environment variable created by kafka script `LOG_DIR` and it's translated as an option in the JVM `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/my/server/log/path`.

So to answer your question:
If you want to delete data from topic, you can try one of those possibilities:

- Delete/recreate the topic
- Set the retention to 0 if you're using `cleanup.policy=delete`, the reset the previous retention when the topic is purged
- use the utility script `kafka-delete-records` to delete messages by their offsets
- And the good solution is set a DeserializationExceptionHandler in your kafka client application to ignore those messages and/or put them in a DLQ topic

**Second recommandation :**

If you're in a production environment, you should :

- use at least **3** brokers
- set the `default.replication.factor` to 3 and the `min.insync.replicas` to 2 in the `server.properties` file (and/or specify it when you create your topic).

This will prevent you from accidents and each data will be replicated on 3 brokers (but there're some other details that I can't list them all here in this answer).

And if you loose one of the brokers or the storage disk of one of the brokers, this data will not be lost because they're already replicated and when you fix and restart your broker it'll synchronize automatically the date that it lost

Comment: thank you sir! I got it but the issue is I don't want to delete data. like if any fatal error is coming I read somewhere that delete the Kafka-logs and zookeeper-logs which you provided in path log.dir and until you do not delete this Kafka won't run again which is true I faced that tell me here if I am wrong. But the issue was that when i deleted that my topics were also got deleted which I don't want to be.

Comment: would you share your config (server.properties) and the error in the log file please

Comment: Oh you're using Kafka under Windows OS, ah that's true, you can have an issue anytime. Kafka on windows is only for testing but not to set a production environment on it

Comment: yep let me share my server.properties file

Comment: so it do not work properly in windows. If so,  using Aiven or something online provider would be helpful for projects ?